# Difference in appearance between alias domains of a WordPress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alias

I have a website:

http://seachangesalt.com/

This website has two aliases:

- http://seachangework.com/
- http://c2bvalue.com/

It links to the same website, same back-end information. In FireFox the alias menu's and banner's font and css seem to change. They are bigger and the menu is even pushed so far that it cuts of 2-3 menu items.

Why would this happen if they are both the same website with just alias? The site is built in WordPress but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Edit: I stand corrected this also happens in IE. Chrome is the only one getting it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did an htaccess edit for it.

```
   <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you linked to the font's css file with an absolute path but the css file itself contains relative paths.  So the browser will try to pull the files from a different domain name than the current alias.  Some browsers try to avoid cross-server vulnerabilities by not allowing this in certain situations. Change the absolute path to a relative path and your problem will go away.

Change this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='customfont-css'  href='http://SeaChangeSalt.com/wp-content/themes/zenon/fonts/yanone_kaffeesatz.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

To this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='customfont-css'  href='wp-content/themes/zenon/fonts/yanone_kaffeesatz.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

So looking at the theme you are using for Wordpress go into the file:

**EDIT**

**/wp-content/themes/zenon/functions.php**

Change this line which is requesting the stylesheet for your font with an absolute url:

```
wp_enqueue_style('customfont',get_template_directory_uri().'/fonts/'.$zn_fonts = of_get_option('font_select', 'yanone_kaffeesatz' ).'.css');
```

and use wp's function to make a makeshift relative url out of the full theme url by changing the line to this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('customfont',wp_make_link_relative(get_template_directory_uri()).'/fonts/'.$zn_fonts = of_get_option('font_select', 'yanone_kaffeesatz' ).'.css');
```

I believe that this is one way to force wordpress to output the proper relative url for that font's stylesheet.

Comment: Make sense. But what file am I changing this in? I don't know 100% about word-press's setup

Comment: Looks like there is a wordpress function called wp_make_link_relative().  I'll edit answer with place to add this

Comment: So close yet so far away....The wp_enqueue_style isn't in /wp-content/themes/zenon/functions.php.

I did find this function in /wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/functions.php but that's not the current template i'm using.